# Is there a way to convert a pl.Series of type pl.Datetime from one timezone to another?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-polars

I am reading a parquet file with `polars` and would like to convert a column called `datetime` from type `datetime[ms, America/New_York]` to `datetime[ns,UTC]`.
I can take the column out and do it in `pandas`, use `tz_convert` and add the column back to polars dataframe but would be nice if there was a way to do it in `polars` :)

Comment: Do you also want to shift the time according to the timezone differences or only set the timezone differently?

Comment: I need also to shift the time: for example `2021-05-04 19:00:00 EDT` should become `2021-05-04 23:00:00 UTC`.
From docs I saw the timezone can be changed with `pl.col("timezone").dt.with_time_zone` but what I'm trying to do is different.

Also, calling `dt.epoch()` on a timezone aware column returns the unix epoch in that timezone (_I'd argue it should always be UTC for epoch_)

Comment: * `pl.col("datetime").dt.with_time_zone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of polars `0.14.14` there is:

`pl.col("datetime").dt.with_time_zone` which sets a timezone without modifying the underlying timestamp.

`pl.col("datetime").dt.cast_time_zone` which modifies the underlying timestamp by correcting from the current timezone the the given timezone.

**EDIT**

As of polars `0.16.3`, there is:

`pl.col("datetime").dt.convert_time_zone` which sets a timezone without modifying the underlying timestamp.

`pl.col("datetime").dt.replace_time_zone` which modifies the underlying timestamp by correcting from the current timezone the the given timezone.